# Question regarding difference between Postgres and oracle in a simple query

Tags: sql, oracle

This may be a simple question, but I am a postgres user, who is starting to work with oracle as well. There are some small errors that I'm getting, and I can't a solution for them.

These are some of the errors that I am getting and haven't figured out:

in postgres, the query

```
select 0 as t1, 2 as t2
union
select 1 as t1, 0 as t2
```

gives me this result:

```
| t1 | t2 |
| 0   | 2           |
| 1   | 0           |
```

but that same code on oracle gives me the following error:

> 923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Another simple problem.

If i run this query in postgres:

```
(select * from foo)
```

I will get all rows from foo. In oracle, that same query gives me the following error:

> 907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.  The databases are different and they have different rules for what constitutes a valid query.  For instance, Oracle requires a `FROM` clause.

Comment: Oracle statements always require a FROM clause -> `select 0 as t1, 2 as t2 FROM DUAL`

Answer (score 2):

Oracle does not allow doing a select without specifying a table.  It makes available the `dual` dummy table for this purpose:

```sql
SELECT 0 AS t1, 2 AS t2 FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 0 FROM dual   -- aliases ignored here
```